# Basic4Android show error when compile - very simple

Tags: android, basic4android

I just install basic4android and want to run my first application on b4a bridge, but I am getting the following error:

```
B4A version: 5.02
Parsing code.    (0.08s)
Compiling code.    (0.36s)
Compiling layouts code.    (0.03s)
Generating R file.    Error
ERROR: Unknown option '--auto-add-overlay'
Android Asset Packaging Tool
Usage:
aapt l[ist] [-v] [-a] file.{zip,jar,apk}
List contents of Zip-compatible archive.
```

What I make wrong?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Android SDK version you are using is too old. You should update to the latest version and check the entries in tools > configure paths are pointing to their correct locations on your PC